# assigning a variable upon binding a relationship in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, properties, sqlalchemy, relationship, descriptor

I have the following two classes:

```
class user(Base):
   ....
   id=Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
   address=relationship('Address',backref='user')

class Address(Base):
   ...
   IsItAssgined=False
   user_id=Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'))
```

Lets create two instances of these classes:

```
Addr=Address()
Tom=User()
```

I would like the following behaviour: upon appending the Addr to the User, The field IsItAssigned in the Address gets updated to True, i.e.

```
Tom.address.append(Addr)
print Addr.IsItAssigned 
-> to be True
```

I don't know how to use descriptors here if possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use a property for that, one that tests if the `user_id` column is not NULL. A [`column_property()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapper_config.html#using-column-property-for-column-level-options) seems appropriate here:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import column_property

class Address(Base):
   ...
   user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'))
   IsItAssigned = column_property(user_id != None)
```

Now `IsItAssigned` will be either `True` or `False`. Alternatively, use a [hybrid property](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapper_config.html#using-a-hybrid):

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import hybrid_property

class Address(Base):
   ...
   user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'))

   @hybrid_property
   def IsItAssigned(self):
       return self.user_id != None
```

A hybrid property has the advantage of being usable in a query as well. Last but not least, for this case, perhaps an ordinary property would do too, it'll only work on already loaded instances though:

```
class Address(Base):
   ...
   user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'))

   @property
   def IsItAssigned(self):
       return self.user_id is not None
```

I'd use a different name, though. `assigned` might be better; the [Python style guide (PEP 8)](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) advocates the `lower_case_with_underscores` for methods and instance attributes.

Comment: Hi Martijn,Thanks for the response, I think I missed something in my description. I may want to set "IsItAssigned" to False later although the address is still assigned to a user! In general, I want to do something with an attribute (call a method on that or...) once at the time that append happens, later I may change it!

Comment: @Amin: In that case you'll need to use [events](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/events.html) instead; when should `IsItAssigned` be set at all? Insert of the address, `user_id` being set to a non-NULL value, or something else?

Comment: Martijn, I am looking at the events. Thanks for sharing. 
It should be set for the first time at the time of user_id being set, but later I want to be able to change it like Addr.IsItAssigned=False

Comment: @Amin: Note that if you use events, the information will not be persisted in the database. The attribute will reset in that case. You should make it a column in that case.

Comment: @Amin: Of course, you can use further events to set the attribute when an instance is loaded, but in my experience things get really complex fast that way.

Comment: @MartijnPieters You have an extra ')' char in your hybrid_property example return statement. Since this was a one character edit, I could not make it myself.